# MUI DatagridPro exit edit when single select is selected

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I created a inRow edit Datagrid. Using the singleSelect option in type on the column.

Defining a valueOptions works well. But when editing and jumping between cells with tab you can't select an option in the menu without exiting row edit mode.

```
{
  field: 'marketId',
  headerName: 'Market',
  flex: 1,
  valueOptions: markets.map(m => ({
    value: m.id,
    label: m.id
  })),
  editable: true,
  type: 'singleSelect'
},
```

I followed some instructions I found on MUI docs for overriding default Mui behaviour like bellow. And that works for other types, like number and date. But not for single select.

```
onRowEditStop={(params, event) => {
  if (params.reason === GridRowEditStopReasons.rowFocusOut) {
     event.defaultMuiPrevented = true
  }
}}
onCellEditStop={(params, event) => {
  if (params.reason === GridCellEditStopReasons.enterKeyDown) {
    event.defaultMuiPrevented = true
  }
}}
```

The only way to select an option in singleSelect is by hitting "enter". But that also exits row edit mode. My expected behaviour is that you stay in the same cell when selecting an option and then you can tab over to the next cell. Could anyone help me achieve that?

Edit:
Setting (params.reason === GridRowEditStopReasons.enterKeyDown) in onRowEditStop seems to make the single select behave as I expect but then I can't commit the row to save.

CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/datagridrowedit-x3cv5s